# Woocommerce CSS box styling

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am having trouble lining up boxes; mind you I am pretty rusty at css. What am I doing wrong? Here is an image of what it looks like.

**Preview:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0zd4.jpg

**Code**

```
.products{ 
padding-left: 15px!important;
padding-bottom: 100px!important;
}
ul.products li.product {    
border:#CC0000 thin solid!important; 
text-align:center!important; 
background-color:#121212!important;
max-height: 375px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to apply min-height to each list item

```
ul.products li.product
```

to assure the height is always set at a minimum. That would be a fairly easy approach for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.products li.product{

 min-height:375px; // or other to fit Your needs but then also change max-height.

}
```